# Reduce the size of horizontal line

Tags: framed, algorithm2e

I want to reduce the size of horizontal line.

```
\begin{frame}
\restylealgo{boxed}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\Setline
\nl i\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the contents of your `algorithm` inside a `minipage` of the appropriate width. Here's an example highlighting this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \RestyleAlgo{boxed}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \nl i\;
  \end{algorithm}

  \bigskip

  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \nl i\;
  \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Also, you should update your version of [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). Since version 4.0, some commands have been modified - I'm using them above.